# Is there any pattern or design pattern to decrease the code from activity or fragment class ? - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I do separate Network operations,  IO operations, and other stuff form the activity class

Still the onClick functions, FindViewById calls, implementation of onCreate, onStop onResume and other lifecycle functions makes the activity code very long, hard to manage and messy...

**Is there any pattern you use that order and decrease the code from the activity class ?**

Comment: Take a look at http://androidannotations.org/

Comment: @Kuffs thank you i will check it out

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to reduce the onClick and findView boilerplate and of course [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) will come in handy.

I order my Activity-Lifecycle methods [according to this diagram](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) and use editor fold comments to group the lifecycle.

```
//<editor-fold desc="Android Lifecycle">

    lifecycle methods come here...

//</editor-fold>
```

Comment: I already use ButterKnife, and instead of <editor-fold .. description, I use `// region Android LifeCycle` and at the end i put at the end `// endregion` and it fold the code .. it helps but a partial solution for the very long activity

Comment: I also struggle with long activities 1k+ Lines of Code, but then again it's a symptom of putting too many resposibilities in that activity. Thats when I start refractoring to use Fragments, CustomViews and CustomDialogues.

Comment: I agree with you, but in my case, I have to put table that contains 10 textviews, 1 CustomAdapter, 3 Customdialogs, and 1 combobox group with 3 comboboxes, and 3 buttons at the end.. I must show them at one page.. in xml I use `<include layout="layout_id/>"`, but for activity i got the mess.. thats why i wanted to get from your experiences.. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to move as much code as you can out of the UI classes. This will allow unit testing and help clean up your code.

You can create Service classes to implement onClick functions so that your onClick function just calls a method in your Service. Then the Service code could be tested without have to start the Activity in your tests.

You can also create a BaseActivity that all others extend and put boilerplate shared code in there.

As far as findViewById you can use a framework like [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/) and use the @InjectView annotation on your variables. I use RoboGuice to create Services and inject those services into my Activities and also inject my views. This cleans it up a lot.

Also, create utility classes where you can. I hope this helps.